# Default uninstall functionality of Setup and Deployment Project can't be executed upon rebuild of setup.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, uninstallation

I created a setup project to install my application (*.bat file) and successfully installed to end-users' pc. And run the same setup.exe to uninstall the installed application.

Now, I enhanced the application by modifying *.bat file, adding external files, etc..

Then, need to update the setup project to add the newly added external files and things go well and rebuild was done.

The problem is, when I execute the newly rebuild setup.exe on the end-users' pc, uninstall functionality was gone. It only says, old version was installed need to uninstall first via control panel.

Why the uninstall functionality of Setup Project is not longer functioning upon creation of new setup.exe?

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: The UpgradeCode and ProductCode properties of a setup project are a big deal.  Did you change them?

Comment: Same result with Pirvu's advise. If you need other information to confirm, please let me know.

Comment: Additional, I tried to install using only the newly created setup project. Here are the steps: 1) Build the project to create setup.exe 2) execute the created setup.exe and successfully installed 3) Rebuild the project to create a second setup.exe 4) upon execution of the second created setup.exe, appears the same error. "...uninstall the program using Control Panel....".

Comment: The above scenario is too strange... it changes something inside the installer upon rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade older versions you can try this:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- in its Properties pane set [RemovePreviousVersions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y63fxdw6%28VS.80%29.aspx) property to **True**
- generate a new Product Code
- increase the Version

These are the main requirements of a [major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Let me to post here some phrases. "During a major upgrade using Windows Installer, the installer searches the user's computer for applications that are related to the pending upgrade, and when it detects one,..." <- How Windows Installer detects product's old version? My application is composed of *.bat, *.jar, *.txt files not a .net application(vb,c#).

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the Version"? Setup Project's version? or the Application's version? For additional information, my application is not .net application (vb, c#).

Comment: I tried the Pirvu's advise. The result was, it replaces all old files with the same name, it removes all files which not included in the new setup project, it creates new folders and adds new files without any notification that it has old version installed. Even Major Upgrade. I think it is necessary to notify first the user. My goal is to appear the Repair/Remove window regardless old version or same version. *If I run twice the new setup.exe, it appears the Repair/Remove window which I expect even on the first run.

Comment: Also I'm receiving a WARNING messages. "WARNING: Could not match culture 'ja-JP' for item 'Windows Installer 3.1'. Using culture 'en' instead." "WARNING: Could not match culture 'ja-JP' for item '.NET Framework 3.5'. Using culture 'en' instead." during new setup project rebuild. The setup project was originally created by Japanese version of VS2008 but now I am using English version of VS2008. Is there any influence?

Comment: Windows Installer searches for older version using the information it stores internally about products. Your files and folders are not used by these searches. During a major upgrade the old version is automatically removed before the new version is installed. If you don't want this, you can try using patches. Visual Studio doesn't support patches, so you would need to use a different setup authoring tool. Regarding the culture, it seems that you are using the Japanese version of some prerequisites. Remove your prerequisites and add them again.